# É possível simular a palavra-chave 'friend' do C++ no Java?

Tags: java

Existe alguma forma de simular isso no Java? Eu gostaria de ter acesso a um construtor privado de uma classe em outra, mas essa outra classe não pode estar aninhada. Isso é para a lógica de um jogo onde eu teria uma classe `Inimigo` e outra `Raca`, e eu preciso fazer com que `Inimigo` seja instanciado apenas usando `Raca`, dessa maneira eu conseguiria definir de uma forma simples a `Raca` do `Inimigo`.

Como nesse exemplo:

```
// Raca
public class Raca {
    private final int dano;
    private int vida;

    public Raca(int vida, final int dano) {
        this.dano = dano;
        this.vida = vida;
    }

    // Chamada de construtor privado
    public Inimigo novoInimigo() { return new Inimigo(this); }

    public int getVida() { return vida; }
    public int getDano() { return dano; }

    // Outros métodos que não nos interessam...
}

// Inimigo
public class Inimigo {
    // Se fosse C++:
    // friend class Raca;

    private int vida;
    private Raca raca;

    private Inimigo(Raca raca) {
        this.raca = raca;
        this.vida = raca.getVida();
    }

    public int getVida() { return raca.getVida(); }
    public int getDano() { return raca.getDano(); }

    // Outros métodos que não nos interessam...
}
```

Faço isso para não ter que criar uma classe diferente para cada tipo de `Inimigo` no jogo (muitos).

Comment: O máximo que você consegue é partilhar métodos dentro do mesmo pacote. Não tem esse "nível" de amizade, apenas: `public` / `protected` / "`package`" / `private`. O escopo de visualização a nível de pacote é obtido através da omissão do modificador de visibilidade

Comment: Você quer instanciar uma classe dentro da outra apenas?

Comment: Sim, é para a lógica de um jogo

Comment: Se puder [edit] a pergunta dando mais detalhes do problema, talvez alguém dê outra solução. Porque não existe um recurso igual em Java (embora [dê para simular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18634125) de um jeito meio maluco - mas não dá pra saber se isso resolve o seu caso, então por favor edite a pergunta, do contrário todas as respostas serão palpites...)

Comment: Sinceramente? Seu código para mim está claro que deveria ser um construtor público. Por que você necessita remover o acesso do construtor de outros cantos?

Comment: Ou então até mesmo usar uma `factory` de inimigos, para criá-los sobre um template. Ou um `builder`

Comment: É isso que eu ia dizer. Se o construtor de `Inimigo` for `public`, ele já funciona com a restrição de "ser instanciado usando apenas `Raca`". Só com o código que está aí, não há justificativa para o construtor ser `private`, e usar reflection pra acessá-lo é uma solução pior do que simplesmente mudar para `public`

Comment: Por que `Raca` tem métodos mais complexos para definir o comportamento daquela `Raca`, e que poderia trazer problemas colocar isso no `Inimigo`. Esse código para comportamento envolve referência a outras partes do jogo, como por exemplo `Render`. Além disso o construtor do `Inimigo` e `Raca` não fazem apenas isso, mas entra no que eu citei acima de se estender em outras partes do jogo. Isso faria eu ter que mostrar como funciona essas outras partes para o código ficar legível, então eu optei por dar um exemplo simples.

Comment: Pela sua descrição, a impressão que passa é que as classes estão fazendo mais coisas que deviam. Talvez se quebrá-las em partes menores (por exemplo, ter uma classe só para definir comportamentos específicos do `Inimigo`, deixar as coisas mais desacopladas do `Render`,  o construtor só devia construir o objeto e pronto, outras coisas não diretamente relacionadas à criação daquela instância deveriam ficar separadas - talvez uma *factory* que encapsule isso seja melhor, etc), não precise usar reflection e o código fique melhor. Enfim, boa sorte :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela descrição da sua questão parece um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/64969), você não precisa utilizar um recurso complexo de outra linguagem apenas para instanciar uma classe com construtor privado no Java.

Seguindo essa linha, em que você gostaria apenas de instanciar uma classe com construtor privado em outro lugar, seguem alguns exemplos considerando a seguinte classe:

```
class MinhaClasse {
    private MinhaClasse() {
        // NOP
    }
}
```

Você pode acessar o construtor via reflection:

```
Constructor<MinhaClasse> constructor = MinhaClasse.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
constructor.setAccessible(true);
MinhaClasse minhaClasse = constructor.newInstance();
```

Ou você pode criar um método estático para devolver a instância para você:

```
class MinhaClasse {
    private MinhaClasse() {
        // NOP
    }

    public static MinhaClasse create() {
        return new MinhaClasse();
    }
}
```

E utilizar `MinhaClasse.create()` onde necessário.

Comment: Imagino que reflexão seja melhor, pois não tenho plano de oferecer a instância da (nesse exemplo) `MinhaClasse` dentro dela mesma.